# HOW CAN I get link of uploaded file with dropbox-sdk-js

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I use [github](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/upload/index.html) sample to upload image file to dropbox and It's OK,

But after upload, **HOW CAN** I get link of uploaded file? Such as:

> `https://www.dropbox.com/s/wiczs1cbhwveq5p/2017_Penguins.jpg?dl=0`

It used to record again (in my database) to download this file later, with:

> javascript/download/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To get a shared link for a file using the [Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js), you can use the [`sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings__anchor) method.

Comment: is there any chance that you show an example on how it's done? I really need it.

Comment: @Miraz I've answered your new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558459/get-link-to-the-uploaded-image-in-dropbox-using-js-and-sdk